# If an algorithm solves an NP problem, for what f(n) can we claim that R belongs to TIME(f(n))?

Tags: complexity-theory, np

Let $R$ be some problem in NP.

Suppose algorithm of solution check M(x,y) runs in time $O(n^3)$ and uses $y$ additional information, s.t $y \leq 5 \log n$ bits.

For what $f(n)$ can we claim that $R$ belongs to $\textbf{TIME}$$(f(n))$?

I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: I am sure rules are correct. The title of task is: algorithms that solve NP problems. If I am right, I have to give answer, which contains for example f(n)=n of f(n)=n^2 and explain it.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Can you think of any deterministic algorithm at all, given the information provided here?  What will its running time be?  We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it.  You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: Also, it's a bit confusing that in one part of the sentence you describe $y$ as the solution and in another part you talk about "uses $y$ additional information".  It's also confusing that you describe $y$ as a solution, but then write $y \le 5 \log n$ bits.  I suspect you mean that the solution $y$ can be expressed with $\le 5 \log n$ bits.  I encourage you to edit the question to clarify these points.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose, for clarity:

- $X$ is the input, and $|X|$ = $n$
- $Y^*$ is a "yes" certificate, $|Y^*| \leq 5\log n$ bits
- $M$ is an algorithm that verifies the instance $X$ given certificate $Y^*$ in
  $O(n^3)$ time.

There are $2^{|Y^*|}$ possible binary certificates of length $|Y^*|$, so algorithm $A$ that checks all possible certificates $Y_i$ of length $5\log n$ will have exactly $ 2^{5\log n} = n^5$ certificates to check.

Since each certificate takes $O(n^3)$ time to verify (with $M$), $A$ will run in $O(n^8)$. If $X \in R$, a certificate $Y^*$ that verifies it exists and $A$ will find it (because it checks them all).

It follows that $A$ accepts $R$ and runs in $O(n^8)$ time, so $R \in \textbf{TIME}(n^8)$